# find extension typed like script argument and access rights

Tags: linux, bash

I trying create "if" statement with arguments like this:

`if [ find $3 -type  f\( -name "*.$1"\) ]`\

and I call script:

`./script .txt .doc ./catalog`

So i want check if in typed catalog $3 , exist any file ending my first typed argument, i don't know how can i fix it ?

My second question, how can i add some access right in this script ? 
Etc. i call this script without access i then only print some String etc. "You have no rights ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if ! [ -r "$3" ]
then
    echo "You have no access rights"
    exit 1
fi
if find "$3" -type f -name "*$1" | grep -q .
then
    echo "Found one!"
else
    echo "No luck."
fi
```

The first `if` statement above checks for access rights to read the directory you selected.  If you don't have read access, it prints a message and exits.

The second `if` statement above checks for the existence of at least one regular file with the extension that you want. It uses the find statement, `find "$3" -type f -name "*$1"` to look for matching files.  The output from it is piped to `grep` which simply tests whether there is any output from the find command.  If there is output, then `grep` returns an exit code of 0 and the `then` statement executed.  If there is no output, `grep` sets an exit code of 1 and the `else` statement executes.

Comment: `grep -q .` could be replaced by `read` (or `read _`), saving one external process!